# The right side of the screen is overlapping the entire left side of questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This started happening to me now where the area on the right side of my screen has "blog" and what appears to be ads under it, is overlapping a question and its content.

This is happening in meta also, not just Stack Overflow.com

Edit: I am on a Linux box using Google Chrome Version 72.0.3626.81 (Official Build) (64-bit), 
with a laptop and 1024x800 resolution.

Note: If I zoom out at 80%, it's fine.

See the screenshot I captured and included below:

[image]

Comment: The screenshot comes from https://stackoverflow.com/q/59184366/ which is the question I was in when this started.

Comment: Was coming here to say as much. I can't even... (－‸ლ)

Comment: @ruffin Maybe they're working on something that is network-wide.

Comment: What is that ad for?

Comment: was going to post the same question .. sometimes it happen only when you edit, example here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59184511/8620333

Comment: [Similar question on meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339651/strange-overlapping-post-layout-and-sidebar)

Comment: @rene I don't know. It was there at the moment I captured the screen.

Comment: @khelwood Thanks. I didn't see that one.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Maybe they should take a look at [this excellent question from a site about software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/1435/61982), but only if their browser window is under about 980px or over 1220. /leSigh ;)

Comment: @ruffin I would most likely fall under that screen size factor. I'm on a laptop with probably 1024x800 type of thing.

Comment: @ruffin somehow expected that to link to Experts-Exchange ...

Comment: for anyone having >10K you can edit my deleted answer below to see the issue of the edit

Comment: @TemaniAfif I see it. Could be a bad div somewhere, hard to say since I'm a bit out of touch with CSS lately.

Comment: Browser/OS? I'm not having any problems in Edge [Chromium] Dev on Win 10...

Comment: they are missing `min-width:0` on `.post-layout--right` and probably other element. This is a common issue in CSS grid (related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43312314/8620333)

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks for the comment. I added that in the question.

Comment: I can reproduce in W10 using Firefox, Chrome, and Edge (legacy) by resizing this question appropriately.

Comment: they are also using `.post-text {
    width: 660px;
}` .. quite strange to fix a width like that

Comment: If it was fixed, I wouldn't be over here now. Only browser that seems to work is the blue e. Seriously - I thought those days were over.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! We deleted a ton of IE-specific CSS and there was some complicated Less logic causing this bug that we didn’t catch in our local environment. This should now be fixed.

Folks, remember, I’m a person. I’m working hard on improving our codebase every day. Some days there will be visual regressions. I’m sure you’ve shipped some.

Comment: It appears to be only when there are code blocks with long lines.

Comment: @monty Exactly. For some reason, the horizontal scrollbar doesn't appear like it did in the past

Comment: Welcome Aaron. I did notice overlaps when being inside the flag summary of my profile a few months back where the flags themselves went wider than the container. I was going to post a question about it then, but hesitated.

Comment: Seems *not* to be fixed actually, unless some CDN is caching something.

Comment: Just did a cache-avoiding refresh where I was seeing it and so I think @DavidSanders that you can blame caching this time.

Comment: Seems to be working now

Comment: Thanks @Aaron Shekey. That's a pretty quick turn around for a live bug fix. Very nice.

Comment: Seems to be ok now Aaron. Anything you can do about the flag summary area also [that I mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391877/the-right-side-of-the-screen-is-overlapping-the-entire-left-side-of-questions#comment743456_391884) earlier? Edit: Or would that constitute as another / new question?

Comment: Yep, works for me now too.  By the way @Draco18s, I had done a cache-avoiding refresh and it wasn't helping.

Comment: I don't think anyone is blaming you for making mistakes. We realize, after all, that you are human, and every single one of us has written buggy code more than once. The sentiment is more, how could your test environment have failed to catch this, and what can be done to improve your test environment so that bugs like this don't get inadvertently pushed to production in the future? I can completely understand edge cases being missed, like bugs that only show up in one browser version. But this one was pretty massive, presenting just about everywhere.

Comment: I'm sorry some people felt the need to pile on and repeatedly report that it wasn't working even when several comments already stated that, and I'm embarrassed that some people went so far to question your team's ability to test fixes before deploying them live. That was done in a very non-constructive way and was wholly inappropriate. Thanks for the first attempt at deploying the fix which didn't work, and for the second attempt that did work.

Comment: I read the deleted comments, @Davy (mod hacks). I confess that I really don't see that one as particularly confrontational. It might be my having an unusually thick skin or something. I could see myself posting a comment like that without meaning any harm. I probably read more as shock/surprise what you are interpreting as confrontational/hostile. To me, there's an implicit assumption that Aaron and the rest of the team *are*, in fact, competent, thus the shock that a bug like this could escape to the "wild". None of this detracts from the props Aaron is rightly due for a fast fix, of course.

Comment: @Aaron Shekey, is there a specific reason for hard-coding various max-widths as `n px` rather than using the space that the browser window provides? In my opinion, things looked better without the white margins on the sides, so if there's no specific reason, I'd prefer to have full width again.

Comment: No need to be defensive--we (generally) assume there are humans on the other side of all software, and that mistakes happen. I think there's an implicit "atta boy" pretty much all the time--but we take SO for granted and don't always call them out. So atta boy!

Comment: @DanielFischer they modified it to use a css grid layout which behaves a little strangely compared to other layouts: ["a grid item cannot be smaller than the size of its content."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43312314/3903479)

Comment: @GammaGames Thanks, but I'm practically illiterate concerning css, so I don't understand the implications of that. Of course it makes sense that a container can't be smaller than its contents, but isn't that only a restriction for min-widths, not for max-widths?